# Show that if $v\in L_{t}^{\infty}L_{x}^{2}\cap L_{t}^{2}L_{x}^{6} $, then $v\in L_{t}^{s}L_{x}^{q}$ for $\frac{3}{q}+\frac{2}{s}=\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fluid-dynamics, function-spaces

Define $L_{t}^{s}L_{x}^{q}$ to be the set of functions defined on the interval $(0,T)$ valued in $L_{x}^{q}$, such that

$$\int_{0}^{T} \lVert v(t,.)\rVert_{q}^s dt<\infty,$$

where $t$ and $x$ indicate corresponding variables. I would like to show that if $v\in L_{t}^{\infty}L_{x}^{2}\cap L_{t}^{2}L_{x}^{6} $, then $v\in L_{t}^{s}L_{x}^{q}$ for $\frac{3}{q}+\frac{2}{s}=\frac{3}{2}$ and $q\in [2,6]$. The hint is that using H$\ddot{o}$lder inequality first in $x$ and then in $t$. Many thanks for any suggestions and solutions.

Comment: With such a hint you are still blocked? What did you try? Did you try to do what the hint is telling ...

Comment: I tried to write $$\int_{0}^{T}(\int v^{q}(t,x)dx)^{s/q}dt\leq\int_{0}^{T}\lVert v(t,.)\rVert_2^{s/q}\lVert v^{q-1}(t,.)\rVert_{2}^{s/q}dt,$$ and then replaced $\lVert v(t,.)\rVert_2$ by a constant. But then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Notice that $\|v^{q-1}\|_2 = \|v\|_{2(q-1)}^{q-1}$. By the way, you used Cauchy-Schwarz, but Hölder is more general in terms of possibilities ...

Comment: Noting this, I wrote $$\int_{0}^{T}\lVert v(t,.)\rVert_{2(q-1)}^{\frac{s(q-1)}{q}}\quad dt.$$ How do I apply Holder inequality for $t$? Or are there any good pair of two conjugate numbers for Holder inequality? Thanks

Comment: You do not need Holder inequality again, you already used it twice, the second time being $\int f g \leq \|f\|_\infty \int |g|$, that is the fact that you put the $L^2$ norm in a constant. Now just look at the conditions so that $2(q-1) = 6$ ;)
But again, when you used Holder's inequality the first time, you should have put $(r,r')$ instead of $(2,2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let me write a more precise solution. First note that for any $1\leq p\leq q\leq r\leq \infty$, defining $\theta$ such that $\frac{1}{q} = \frac{1-\theta}{p} + \frac{\theta}{r}$), by Hölder's inequality
$$
\int |v|^q = \int |v|^{q(1-\theta)} |v|^{q\theta}  \leq \|v\|_{L^p}^{q\,(1-\theta)} \, \|v\|_{L^r}^{q\,\theta}
$$
since $\frac{q(1-\theta)}{p} + \frac{q\theta}{r} = 1$. This gives what is also called sometimes an interpolation inequality.
$$
\|v\|_{L^q} \leq \|v\|_{L^p}^{1-\theta} \, \|v\|_{L^r}^{\theta}.
$$
In particular, in your case, since $2\leq q \leq 6$,
$$
\|v\|_{L^q} \leq \|v\|_{L^2}^{1-\theta} \, \|v\|_{L^6}^{\theta}.
$$
with $\theta = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{3}{q}$. Hence
$$
\int_0^T\|v\|_{L^q}^s\,\mathrm d t \leq \|v\|_{L^\infty_tL^2_x}^{s(1-\theta)}\int_0^T \, \|v\|_{L^6}^{s\theta}\,\mathrm d t.
$$
In particular, choosing $\theta$ such that $s\theta = 2$ is equivalent to choose $q$ such that $s \,(\frac{3}{2} - \frac{3}{q})= 2 \iff \frac{3}{q} + \frac{2}{s} = \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and in particular for the recall of the interpolation!